# Warning message when doing spatial join nearest neighbor on GeoPandas

Tags: python, point, geopandas, spatial-join, nearest-neighbor

I am trying a nearest neighbor spatial join with two point Geodataframes but a warning message is appearing.

My code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

yield_2013=gpd.read_file('https://github.com/kevinkuranyi/archive/raw/main/Brazil_Maize_yield_2013.shp')
temperature=gpd.read_file('https://github.com/kevinkuranyi/archive/raw/main/Temperature_2013.shp')
print(yield_2013.crs)
print(temperature.crs)
df=yield_2013.sjoin_nearest(temperature)
```

The following warning message is shown:

```
UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'sjoin_nearest' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.
```

When I print both CRS the result is the same: `EPSG:4674`. If I follow the warning message instructions and do:

```
df=yield_2013.to_crs(epsg=4674).sjoin_nearest(temperature.to_crs(epsg=4674))
```

The same warning message appears. I manually checked a dozen of points from the resulting file and it seems to be ok, but I have thousands of points and this message (likely incorrect) is making me afraid.

Am I doing the spatial join in the wright way?

Comment: SIRGAS 2000 is a GeogCS (based on GRS 1980).  Cartesian degree distance measurements are useless, so the message is correct.

Comment: @Vince, could you please clarify a bit and make it an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A geographic CRS like EPSG:4674 wraps your coordinates around the surface of a sphere or [ellipsoid](https://epsg.io/4674), but that really complicates things when quantifying distance. Now that you're on a sphere, your distances are going to be represented by an angle (degrees) which are of little practical use.  And then you have to use a set of trigonometric functions (geodesy) just to convert them to a human-interpretable unit of measurement. Spatial projections (projected CRS) have been developed to solve this problem. They simplify the measurement of distance, shape and/or area and save you from having to perform mathematical transformations.

As for `geopandas`, if we refer to the docs about [sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html), we understand that

> Every operation in GeoPandas is planar, i.e. the potential third
> dimension is not taken into account.

In other words, we should project our coordinates onto a 2D plane if we want the spatial join to be accurate.  A good choice for Brazil would be [EPSG:32723](https://epsg.io/32723) , because UTM projections are conformal and the units of measurement are meters.

```py
yield_2013_projected = yield_2013.to_crs(epsg=32723)
temperature_projected = temperature.to_crs(epsg=32723)
df=yield_2013_projected.sjoin_nearest(temperature_projected)
```